# Upload multiple files to Firebase Storage and when all uploads are finished, subscribe to forkJoin

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

I'm working on an upload form that need to upload all files and when all uploads are completed, I want to subscribe on them and trigger next action.

My current implementations that doesn't work:

```
 private uploadImages(): Observable<Subscription> {
const uploadImages$: Subscription [] = [];
this.testResponse.answers.forEach(answer => {
  const filePath = `${answer.selectedImage.name.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')}_${new Date().getTime()}`;
  uploadImages$.push(this.testService.uploadPhoto(filePath, answer.selectedImage).subscribe((url: string) => {
      answer.imageUrl = url;
      delete answer.selectedImage;
      delete answer.id;
    }));
});
return forkJoin(uploadImages$);}

  public uploadPhoto(filePath: string, selectedImage?: UploadMetadata): Observable<string | UploadTaskSnapshot> {
return this.storage.upload(filePath, selectedImage).snapshotChanges().pipe(finalize(async () => this.getDownloadUrl(filePath))); }



  public getDownloadUrl(filePath: string): Observable<string> {
return this.storage.ref(filePath).getDownloadURL(); }
```

1.How can "I wait" until the downloadUrl is provided in the pipe(finalize(async()...)?

2.Do you have a better implementation for upload files to Firebase using Angular?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
forkJoin(uploadImages$).pipe(
  map((photos) => {
    return photos.map(p => p.url);
  }),
  switchMap((photoUrls) => {
    return forkJoin(photoUrls.map(photoUrl => this.getDownloadUrl(photoUrl)));
  })
)
.subscribe((downloadUrls) => {
  console.log(downloadUrls);
});
```